# How to edit FTP accounts in Jcraft SFTP plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, sftp

I've been using the jcraft Eclipse SFTP plugin for FTP manipulation for a few months. However I don't know how to delete an existing FTP account or edit details. If I misspell my username/password or I do change my password, my account stays the same forever.

Where are these details saved and how can I change details? Also, I do have one FTP hostname with few different accounts but I am not able to reuse the same hostname twice.

I already tried reinstalling the plugin, changing the workspace and deleting the plugin physically. No effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you are looking for is:

`pathToEclipseWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/projectName/org.eclipse.team.core/.deployments`

The words in camel-back are things you need to fill in for yourself.

From here, you can delete a "provider" (the one you messed up), then restart Eclipse.  Eclipse should act as if there wasn't a connection in the first place when you try to synchronize again.

I am unsure of whether or not you can edit the details and have Eclipse use the new ones, that will be something you get to test for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Check the preferences page for the plugin.

[EDIT] Contact the plugin author via [the plugin's homepage](http://www.jcraft.com/eclipse-sftp/).

Comment: I've checked for anything related to ftp, sftp, jcraft, webdav etc... no options in the preferences

Comment: I already did, but still no answer from them. That's my only option so far.

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse Indigo on Windows, I found it under

```
C:\Users\<your_user_name>\AppData\Local\Eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\<your_project_name>\org.eclipse.team.core\.deployments
```